# python operator precedence of in and comparison

Tags: python

The following comparisons produce `True`:

```
>>> '1' in '11'
True
>>> ('1' in '11') == True
True
```

And with the parentheses the other way, I get a TypeError:

```
>>> '1' in ('11' == True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: argument of type 'bool' is not iterable
```

So how do I get `False` with no parentheses?

```
>>> '1' in '11' == True
False
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The Python manual says `in` and `==` are of equal [precedence](https://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence). Thus, they're evaluated from left to right by default, but there's also chaining to consider. The expression you put above (`'1' in '11' == True`) is *actually* being evaluated as...

```
('1' in '11') and ('11' == True)
```

which of course is `False`. If you don't know what chaining is, it's what allows you to do something like...

```
if 0 < a < 1:
```

in Python, and have that mean what you expect ("a is greater than 0 but less than 1").

Answer (score 9):

It has nothing to do with precedence. In Python relational operators chain, and containment is considered a relational operator. Therefore:

```
'1' in '11' == True
```

is the same as:

```
('1' in '11') and ('11' == True)
```

which is false since `True` is not equal to "11".

Answer (score 2):

[Chaining](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#notin) allows you to write `x < y < z`, and mean `x < y and y < z`.  Look at this interaction:

```
>>> (False == True) == False
True
>>> False == (True == False)
True
>>> False == True == False
False
>>>
```

So in your example, `'1' in '11' == True` is equivalent to `('1' in '11') and ('11' == True)`