# Python: print "word" in [] == False

Tags: python

Going a bit mental here trying to work out what this does in python:

```
print "word" in [] == False
```

Why does this print `False`?

Comment: If you are expecting output of `True`, you need to group the `"word" in []` in parens: `print ("word" in []) == False`

Comment: comparing with booleans is pointless.

Comment: possible duplicate of [python operator precedence of in and comparision](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7479808/python-operator-precedence-of-in-and-comparision)

Comment: This would be more on topic at http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Why don't you just use `print "word" not in []`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Perhaps a more clear example of this unusual behaviour is the following:

```
>>> print 'word' in ['word']
True
>>> print 'word' in ['word'] == True
False
```

---

Your example is equivalent to:

```
print ("word" in []) and ([] == False)
```

This is because two boolean expressions can be combined, with the intention of allowing this abbreviation:

```
a < x < b
```

for this longer but equivalent expression:

```
(a < x) and (x < b)
```

Comment: is there any way to see how Python evaluates this internally? something like sql explain

Comment: @F.C.: You can do `import dis; dis.dis(lambda: 'word' in [] == False)` but it's quite tricky to read it.

Comment: -1: "unexpected behaviour".  It's far from unexpected.  It's unusual because the construct is unusual.  But it's far from unexpected.  The expression rules are quite clear on this.  Aren't they?  http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html

Answer (score 3):

Just like you can chain operators in `23 < x < 42`, you can do that with `in` and `==`.

`"word" in []` is `False`
and
`[] == False` evaluates to `False`. Therefore, the whole result is

```
"word" in [] == False
"word" in [] and [] == False
False and False
False
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to Mark Byers great answer

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(lambda: 'word' in [] == False)
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('word')
              3 BUILD_LIST               0
              6 DUP_TOP             
              7 ROT_THREE           
              8 COMPARE_OP               6 (in)
             11 JUMP_IF_FALSE_OR_POP    21
             14 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (False)
             17 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             20 RETURN_VALUE        
        >>   21 ROT_TWO             
             22 POP_TOP             
             23 RETURN_VALUE        
>>> dis.dis(lambda: ('word' in []) == False)
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('word')
              3 LOAD_CONST               2 (())
              6 COMPARE_OP               6 (in)
              9 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (False)
             12 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             15 RETURN_VALUE
```