# if 'x' and 'y' in 'z':

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm making sort of a Q&A script in python.  It gets raw_input, and sets it as theQuestion.  I tried `if 'var1' and 'var2' in theQuestion:`, but it looks for either string, not both.  Is there a way I can make this work in one 'if' statement? (not 'if x:     if y:   then z).

Comment: possible duplicate of [python operator precedence of in and comparision](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7479808/python-operator-precedence-of-in-and-comparision)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`and` is a logical AND, not a natural-language one. Therefore, your code gets interpreted as:

```
'var1' and 'var2' in theQuestion
True   and 'var2' in theQuestion # Since bool('var1') == True
           'var2' in theQuestion
```

You want to connect the two tests with a logical AND:

```
if 'var1' in theQuestion and 'var2' in theQuestion:
```

Alternatively, for large numbers of tests:

```
if all(k in theQuestion for k in ('var1', 'var2')):
```

Comment: Or, more generally, `if all(var in theQuestion for var in vars)` where `vars` is `(var1, var2)` in this case.

Comment: @agf Added that too, although it's more of an example how to write obfuscated code in Python, too.

Comment: How would you write it if you didn't know how many vars there were? Or if there were ten variables? I think it's perfectly readable. "If all of the following things are true: the variable is present in theQuestion for each variable in the list of variables"

Comment: @agf You're right in that using `all` is definitely the right thing to do if the number of tests is variable. It's just overkill for exactly two values, since you can't read it as easily as the naive version.

Comment: Agreed. That's why I posted it as a comment, and not an answer; you were already doing it right :)

Comment: With `all` is a nice solution when we have a large list of things to test

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
if 'x' in z and 'y' in z:
  ... do something ...
```