# When checking if an item does not exist in a list, why doesn't this code work - if item in list == False:

Tags: python

Consider this list:

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

I want to check if the number 9 is not present in this list. There are 2 ways to do this.

Method 1: This method works!

```
if not 9 in list: print "9 is not present in list"
```

Method 2: This method does not work.

```
if 9 in list == False: print "9 is not present in list"
```

Can someone please explain why method 2 does not work?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7479808/python-operator-precedence-of-in-and-comparision

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is due to [comparison operator chaining](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in). From the documentation:

> Comparisons can be chained arbitrarily, e.g., `x < y <= z` is equivalent to `x < y and y <= z`, except that `y` is evaluated only once (but in both cases `z` is not evaluated at all when `x < y` is found to be false).

You are assuming that the `9 in list == False` expression is executed as `(9 in list) == False` but that is not the case.

Instead, python evaluates that as `(9 in list) and (list == False)` instead, and the latter part is never True.

You really want to use the `not in` operator, and *avoid* naming your variables `list`:

```
if 9 not in lst:
```

Comment: Thanks! I was not aware of the concept of operator chaining.

Answer (score 4):

It should be:

`if (9 in list) == False: print "9 is not present in list"`

Comment: Outer parentheses are completely unnecessary.

Comment: @grc Pretty sure they are invalid as well.