# What is the precedence of the "in" operator?

Tags: python, python-3.x, operators, boolean-logic

Today I encountered a difficult situation in this Python program:

```
a = [False, True]
x = True in a in a
y = True in a in [a]
z = True in a in (a)
print(x, y, z)
```

The output of this code is

```
False True False
```

How is it possible?

Let's test for `x` here:

```
x = True in a in a
```

`True in [False, True]` is `True`, and again `True in [False, True]` is `True`.

So `x` should be `True`. But when I run the program it says `False`.

And now let's come from right to left:

```
x = True in a in a
```

`[False, True] in [False, True]` is `False`, so now `True in False` might be a type error or some other error.

Could you please explain this?

Comment: What is about `a` initial value?

Comment: Python chains certain operators, including `in`.

Comment: Essentially the same as [python operator precedence of in and comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7479808/python-operator-precedence-of-in-and-comparison)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python chains certain operators, including `in`.

This:

```
True in a in [a]
```

means

```
(True in a) and (a in [a])
```

so if `a` is equal to `[False,True]`, then the expression is true.

---

The other versions:

```
True in a in a
True in a in (a)
```

are equivalent to each other. Putting parentheses around `(a)` doesn't change its type or its value.

Both mean `(True in a) and (a in a)`, so unless `a` contains itself, they are false.