# True not equal to negative<0

Tags: python, logic, comparison-operators

I feel like I'm missing something simple here, but googling this bring up lots of generic results:

Comparing True to the result of x<0 returns unintuitive results (namely that True is not equal to -1<0).  I assumed this must be order of operations, but neither order produces the same result.

```
>>>True!=-1<0
True
>>> True!=(-1<0)
False
>>> (True!=-1)<0
False
```

What is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extrapolating from this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/7479836/5666087), I believe the answer comes down to chaining of the operators. `!=` and `<` have equal precedence, so they are evaluated left-to-right. But because of chaining, this seems to be happening:

```py
>>> (True != -1) and (-1 < 0)
True
```

Compare this with OP's original code:

```py
>>> True != -1 < 0
True
```

---

The author of the StackOverflow answer I posted above includes this example to explain chaining:

```py
0 < a < 1
```

which is evaluated as

```py
(0 < a) and (a < 1)
```

Answer (score 3):

I think it's evaluating the two conditions separately, not grouping them.

Take the below:

```
>>> -1 != 0 < 1
True
```

It's evaluating it as `(-1 != 0)` AND `(0 < 1)`.

With your example:

```
True != -1 => this is True
-1 < 0 => this is True
```

So the combination of 2 True is True.