# How to create a list of the most common key in a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary which is as follows, titled city_dict:

```
{'Jacksonville': 4, 'Shanghai': 7, 'Houston': 3, 'Los Angeles':3}
```

I want to put the cities with the highest counts (values) in a list. I have a variable max_count initialized to 0. To obtain the highest count my code is:

```
max_count=0
for i in city_dict.values():
    if i > max_count:
        max_count = i
```

I have an empty list called max_city. I want to populate the list with the cities that match the max_count. In this case, I get my max_count as 7 and I want to populate the max_city list with Shanghai.

I tried the following code:

```
max_city=[]
for city in city_dict.values():
    if city in city_dict.values() == max_count:
        max_city = city
```

However, I am getting an empty list as an output when I am expecting Shanghai. What can I do? I don't want to import any additional modules or libraries to do this. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The condition `if city in city_dict.values() == max_count:` does something probably you don't want.

Comment: The title of your question is not what you are asking. It looks like you want the key for the maximum value in your dict. Also: why a list, if you only need one result?

Comment: This question is identical, except for the list bit. You can of course just put the result in a list. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268272/getting-key-with-maximum-value-in-dictionary

Comment: Try this as well [How do I sort a dictionary by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/how-do-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-value)

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't make much sense.

This loop...

```
for city in city_dict.values():
```

Is just going to loop over a list of numbers. `city_dict.values()` will return something like `[4, 7, 3, 3]`:

```
>>> cities={'Jacksonville': 4, 'Shanghai': 7, 'Houston': 3, 'Los Angeles':3}
>>> cities.values()
dict_values([4, 7, 3, 3])
```

Your `if` expression...

```
if city in city_dict.values() == max_count:
```

...will always return `False`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7479808/python-operator-precedence-of-in-and-comparison) for details.

It sounds like you just want to sort the dictionary by value and return the last item:

```
>>> cities={'Jacksonville': 4, 'Shanghai': 7, 'Houston': 3, 'Los Angeles':3}
>>> sorted(cities.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])[-1]
('Shanghai', 7)
```

Comment: Fair enough. It's invalid in either case. I've updated the question with a link to the referenced answer.