# How does Python parse `7 in x == True`?

Tags: python, operator-precedence

I saw a [question on es.stackoverflow.com](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/611715/349223) in which the author tried to explicitly compare the result of a boolean expression to `True`.

```python
if nota in lista1 == True:
    ...
```

I wasn't sure of the operator precedence myself, so I tried this in the python3 repl:

```
solomon@Solomons-Macintosh ~ % python3
Python 3.9.6 (default, May  7 2023, 23:32:44) 
[Clang 14.0.3 (clang-1403.0.22.14.1)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 
>>> x = [3, 7]
>>> (7 in x) == True
True
>>> 7 in x == True
False
>>> 7 in (x == True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: argument of type 'bool' is not iterable
```

How does Python parse `7 in x == True`? It's not the same as `(7 in x) == True` because it returns a different result. It's not the same as `7 in (x == True)` because it doesn't raise an error. So what *is* it? What does it mean?

Comment: Have you considered using the `dis` module to disassemble the expression and look at how it's executed?

Comment: Just like `2 < x < 4` means `(2 < x) and (x < 4)`, so `7 in x == True` means `(7 in x) and (x == True)`. See: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons (other parts of the documentation are less explicit as to whether `in` is a "comparison" for chaining purposes, but it is.)

Comment: See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/7479808/3001761

Comment: You can use `print(ast.dump(ast.parse("..."), indent=2))` to see the actual syntax tree produced by all three versions of the expression. Without parentheses, it's a *single* comparison expression that involves 2 operators, rather than one comparison nested as an argument in the other.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, Yup. That's it. Bizarre ****ing language! And not the least because `x` is _truthy_ in this case, in spite of the fact that `x==True` is `False`.

Comment: Have to assume this is rarely used by people with knowledge and always misused by people without knowledge.

Comment: I've found one use that I quite like, in the tictactoe questions people sometimes post on here. `if board[0]==board[4]==board[8] in 'XO':` seems quite neat.

Comment: Also something like `if small_string in big_string in huge_string:` could be useful, though one could object that that only shows that `in` should be allowed to chain with itself, not with other comaprison operators.

Comment: To some extent, this provides a good reason to never use `== True`, since `x == True` has the same value as Boolean `x` in the first place.

Comment: Do you understand Spanish? Yussef's answer with four upvotes seems wrong and even contradicting itself, but I'm only reading Google's translation...

Comment: @KellyBundy, I'm trying to learn a bit of Spanish in anticipation of a trip to Latin America. I'm not sure if I completely understand Yusef's answer, but he seems to think that it's a precedence problem. He does not seem to know about chaining.

Comment: Ah, I just realized their answer isn't contradicting itself. Instead it's additionally confusing comparisons and conditional expressions.

Comment: @KellyBundy Exactly, that was my mistake